# Telegram бот отправляет изображение не самостоятельно (C#, Telegram.Bot)

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

По задумке, бот должен **самостоятельно** отправлять изображение пользователю, но почему-то он отправляет картинку лишь после сообщения.
Скорее всего, это связано с тем, как бот получает chat.id.

Задача бота: в указанное время отправить изображение пользователю, без команды.

Ошибка: бот отправляет сообщение в указанное время, но лишь после любого сообщения со стороны пользователя.

Код:

```
using System;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using Telegram.Bot.Args;

namespace iBot
{
    class Program
    {      

        public static DateTime timeReplacement = DateTime.Parse("19:14");
        private static TelegramBotClient client;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;

            client = new TelegramBotClient(Config.ApiToken);        
            
            client.StartReceiving();
            client.OnMessage += Replacement;

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async void Replacement(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)
        {
            var chatId = messageEventArgs.Message.Chat.Id;
            DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;

            if (nowTime.ToShortTimeString() == timeReplacement.ToShortTimeString())
            {
                await client.SendPhotoAsync(chatId, Config.Link);
                client.StopReceiving();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

update: chat.id, по моей задумке, должно браться из первоначальной инициализации, по команде /start. (то бишь, по самому запуску бота)

Comment: `client.OnMessage` вызывается только при новых сообщениях, которые не были получены ранее

Comment: Почему нельзя вызывать метод просто в Main?

Comment: И вместо сравнения времени лучше используй Timer из WinForms или погугли, так как `nowTime.ToShortTimeString() == timeReplacement.ToShortTimeString()` может не сработать никогда

Comment: Что бы знать Id чата в который нужно оправить фото, его можно просто сохранить куда-либо заранее, по-хорошему сделать отдельную запись в табличке БД

Comment: @KuzCode, бот должен быть публичным, разве id чата будет для всех пользователей одинаковым?

Comment: @KuzCode, каким образом можно организовать отправку сообщений вручную ботом, если событие OnMessage здесь не подходит?

Comment: `await client.SendPhotoAsync(chatId, Config.Link);` - эта строка и отсылает фотку в нужный чат

Comment: Конечно же id у всех разный, всем кому вы хотите отправить фото, вы должны сохранить их ChatId, при первом сообщении, например